# Problem with storing data in Firebase (_isScalar: false)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a form that stores the course type data in the Firebase. When I try to save a new element it creates this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXO1z.jpg.
Here's my code in **create-course Component**:

```
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: [''],
    code: [''],
    ects: [''],
    lekt: ['']
  })
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dataStorageService : DataStorageService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  onSaveData(){
    this.dataStorageService.storeCourses();
  }
```

Here's the code in the **service component** :

```
storeCourses(){
        const courses = this.courseService.getCourses();
        this.http.put(
            'https://projekti-ff52b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/courses.json',
             courses)
             .subscribe(response => {
                 console.log(response);});
    }
```

```
getCourses() {        
 return of(this.courses);  }
```

private courses: Course[] = [];

And Course [] is an exported interface from course model.ts

Comment: What does `this.courseService.getCourses()` return?

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, with the edit link right under it.